# I am looking for a manga with female mc in eyeglasses. She is not an immortal in the world full of immortal

Tags: story-identification, manga

World full of immortal, gore is considered as comedy and pretty much if someone got sick they just need a gun to kill themselves just so they can regenerate and return to life. However Female Mc is a part of organization in secret, where she is not an immortal and can disable the immortal if the immortal fell in love with the mortal human. Fmc has a short black hair and wear eyeglasses.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[Immortal Hounds](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/immortal-hounds)***...?

> In another reality, humans never die. If they get sick or injured, they simply "kill" themselves—and immediately come back to life. But then a mysterious new disease, Resurrection Deficiency Syndrome, starts spreading through the populace via Vectors. The Anti-Vector Police Task Force is determined to solve the mystery of how RDS spread, but the Escape Artists who use violent means to rescue Vectors seriously hamper the police's efforts. And just how do the Escape Artists always beat the cops to the scene of the crime…?

As indicated in the summary above, the story takes place in an alternate reality where most people instantly resurrect if they die, healing any injuries or illnesses they were suffering from in the process. As such, it's normal for a friend or loved one to 'kill' you if you get injured.

However, a minority are infected with a communicable disease called RDS (Resurrection Deficiency Syndrome) which prevents you from resurrecting if you die. These people are referred to as Vectors, and the authorities have assembled an Anti-Vector Police Task Force to hunt them people down and euthenise them.

One of the main characters is Kazama Rin, a young woman with short black hair and spectacles. She's an "escape artist" who helps rescue and shelter Vectors from the Anti-Vector Police Task Force, using firearms to blow holes through and dismember any immortals who try to stop her.

One specific character she helps is Kouda Teruyoshi, a male Vector who was romantically involved with an immortal woman, Shinichi Ikumi. Ikumi's older brother, Kenzaki, is a detective who's placed in charge of the Anti-Vector Unit, and unbeknownst to him, Kazama Rin is a member of his staff.

[image]